# How to let KDE on Debian show emojis?

Tags: debian, kde, emoji

I am using KDE on Debian (both stable/Bullseye and testing/Bookworm). Emojis are not displayed in the terminal, not in window titles and not in system notifications.

One way to reproduce the problem is to open https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YaYoJziCgto as it will cause plenty of emojis to be displayed in the window title bar. I only see these "missing font rectangles". Another one is to run `echo "Heart Face Emoji "`; it will display an empty box too.

The problem does not appear on Xfce/Bookworm and KDE on Ubuntu. The problem persists on KDE/Bookworm when using Wayland.

Since the problem does appear on KDE/Bookworm but not on Xfce/Bookworm, I think one can conclude that all required packages, e.g. `fonts-noto-color-emoji` are installed. I have not changed anything in the font settings.

How can I enable emoji rendering in KDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a problem with Qt, not with KDE. For some reason, Debian does not configure fallback fonts and Qt would rely on this.

See [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1006685) for more details.

In a nutshell, one has to put [an appropriate config file](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104542) in `/etc/fonts/conf.avail` and then to rebuild the fonts cache with `sudo fc-cache -fv`.